# Is there a way to import / use SSMS snippets in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssms, code-snippets

I'm using the [MS SQL extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-mssql.mssql) to help with intelliSense and refactoring my SQL code. Its working quite nicely.

I've got a few really simple snippet in SSMS (it's like a copy paste of sql code). I've been searching for an extensions or a way to use or convert SSMS .snippet files in VS code.

Do you have any idea of how to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: if they are simple just retype in VSC, or write a simple python script

Comment: @Iannick, are referring to have snippets in your vs code, once option using custom snippets in VS code, like [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets#_create-your-own-snippets) and select sql.json one